# Thread difference

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps

Just a quick question, I have google maps on an app I am making and the first screen is relatively complicated (there will be a splashscreen at a later date)
The question is what is the difference between these:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                // we start a thread as maps can take some time to start, the app starts much faster this way
                // we do not "have" to do this but its the best option
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    //we need to run on a UI thread as they are GUI interfaces, would crash otherwise
                    public void run()
                    {
                        setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);
                        CheckGPS();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Option 2:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    //we need to run on a UI thread as they are GUI interfaces, would crash otherwise
                    public void run()
                    {
                        setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);
                        CheckGPS();
                    }
                });
```

Which of these is best to use, my application initiates google maps, but I want it to do that within a thread to ensure the user has the best experience, loading times were slightly faster on a slow device so I know it's helping but want to know which is the bset option to use. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method will essentially create a new thread, and then use the main UI thread to do

```
setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);
CheckGPS();
```

and the second one will simply do this work on the main UI thread without creating a new thread. Unless you are doing something BEFORE setting up the map, the first method (creating a new thread) seems pointless as it will be done on the main UI thread anyway.

On another note, I would recommend looking into using an AsyncTask. It is used for situations like this and has a method to do work on the UI thread and also do work in the background.